# how can I make the child divs of a flex container have the same spacing using flexbox?

Tags: css

I want to do something like this image,

[image]

but I do not know how to ensure that between each column there is a separation of `20px` between each column. I am doing      `margin-right: 20px;` but I will have a problem with the last column.
What is the best practice to solve this using `flexbox`?

```css
.flex_container{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100%;
}

.flex_container div{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid blue;
 margin-right: 20px;
 background:yellow;
 height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div>col 1</div>
  <div>col 2</div>
  <div>col 3</div>
  <div>col 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to use gap property

Comment: @Sfili_81 this works, can you put your answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `gap:20px;` to your flex container

```css
.flex_container{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100%;
  gap: 20px;
  
}

.flex_container div{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid blue;
 /*margin-right: 20px; not necessary*/
 background:yellow;
 height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div>col 1</div>
  <div>col 2</div>
  <div>col 3</div>
  <div>col 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know this property, thanks ! :)

Comment: You answer is also correct

Answer (score 2):

This workaround targets all children but the last one :)

```css
.flex_container{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100%;
}

.flex_container div{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid blue;
 background:yellow;
 height:400px;
}

.flex_container div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div>col 1</div>
  <div>col 2</div>
  <div>col 3</div>
  <div>col 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people have already pointed to setting "gap" on the container. But also, remove width and margin from the flex items and set flex-grow instead.

```
.flex_container{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100%;
  gap: 20px;
}

.flex_container div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  background:yellow;
  height:400px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content` property too to have a equal space like in below snippet :

[See more about `justify-content` here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)

> But as you use it you will see it works when `width` have to be in absolute values

```css
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.flex_container div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div>col 1</div>
  <div>col 2</div>
  <div>col 3</div>
  <div>col 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not what the op want

Comment: Yes, changed to `space-between` and what does OP mean can you tell @Sfili_81

Comment: @Rana, `OP` means `original poster` :)